# Need to requests.get a cookie (ASP.NET_SessionID) and then requests.post, the cookie as a parameter

Tags: python, asp.net, post, python-requests, sessionid

I am having trouble getting a cookie, passing it to my parameters list and then posting that cookie using the requests lib.

I've trapped the post with Burpsuite and sessionId is one of the parameters see screenshot below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztGuk.jpg

Source code for the web page is in the screenshot below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsGJ4.jpg

My code is included below:

```
import requests
import cookielib
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print "Enter the url",
url = raw_input
print url
r = requests.get(url)
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c)

#Finding Captcha
div1 = soup.find('div', id='Custom')
comment = next(div1.children)
captcha = comment.partition(':')[-1].strip()
print captcha

#Finding viewstate
viewstate = soup.findAll("input", {"type" : "hidden", "name" : "__VIEWSTATE"})
v = viewstate[0]['value']
print v

#Finding eventvalidation
eventval = soup.findAll("input", {"type" : "hidden", "name" : "__EVENTVALIDATION"})
e = eventval[0]['value']
print e

# Get Cookie (this is where I am confused), and yes I have read through the Requests and BS docs
s = r.cookies
print s # Prints the class call but I don't get anything I can pass as a parameter

#Setting Parameters
params = { 
          '__VIEWSTATE' : v,
          'txtMessage'  : 'test',
          'txtCaptcha'  : captcha,
          'cmdSubmit'   : 'Submit',
          '__EVENTVALIDATION' : e
          #Need ASP.NET_SessionId Key : Value here
}

#Posting
requests.post(url, data=params)

print r.status_code
```

So to be clear, I am trying to take the sessionId when I connect with the web server and use it as a parameter to post to this message board. This is for a lab on a sandboxed VM, not a live site. This is my first time writing a post in Python so if I have it wrong I've done the best I can reading through the Lib documentation and other websites.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass "s" as a parameter to your post.

```
s = r.cookies
print s # Prints the class call but I don't get anything I can pass as a parameter
```

You need to pass the cookies as a parameter named "cookies".  Inside the source code in https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py, it says that cookies can either be a CookieJar or a dictionary containing the cookies you want to pass.

In your case, it is easier to just copy your cookies over to the next post,no need to convert them to dictionary.

## Setting Parameters

```
params = { 
         '__VIEWSTATE' : v,
         'txtMessage'  : 'test',
         'txtCaptcha'  : captcha,
         'cmdSubmit'   : 'Submit',
          '__EVENTVALIDATION' : e
          #Need ASP.NET_SessionId Key : Value here
}

#Posting
requests.post(url, data=params,cookies=s)
```

However, I would strongly suggest you use a requests.Session() object.

```
session = requests.Session()
session.get(url)
session.get(url2)
#It will keep track of your cookies automatically for you, for every domain you use your session on . Very handy in deed, I rarely use requests.get unless I don't care at all about cookies.
```

Comment: How would this look in regards to the code i am writting? Do i call up the session object s and run the get and post through the object so that all cookies and parameters stay persistent? I am learning the requests library as I go.

Comment: Yes,basically instead of calling requests.get()
you would create a session first.
session = requests.Session()

and then you would call the same method you are trying to call but on the session object.

the session only keeps track of your cookies not your parameters. YOu will need to change the parameters as you wish for every post and get you want to make.

Comment: Great thanks let me try it out and I'll circle back.